# Get API Data Using Fetch in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

**Hello guys, I am trying to get Data in My React Component By Calling an API By Using fetch function. I have the folder structure like Below.**

1) **src->components**(All of my components placed here.)

2) **src->services**(file which contain functions to call API.)

Below is my component, Where i am calling the function from services file to get API Data.

```
import React from 'react';
import {getApiData} from '../services/';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      result:''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const data =  getApiData();
    console.log(data);
  }
  render(){
    return(
     <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And Below is my code of services file to get the data from API & then return it.

```
  export function getApiData(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then((data)=>data.json())
    .then((res)=>res)
  }
```

And When i console to my fetch function, used in services file. I got the following result.

**Promise** {pending}
**proto**: Promise
[[**PromiseStatus**]]: "resolved"
[[**PromiseValue**]]: undefined
VM370:3 {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}

**Note:** I don't want to use axios.

Comment: So what's the problem with using fetch? I can see `data = getApiData()` won't work but I don't understand your question, are you unsure how to use Promises?

Comment: Is getApiData method in your /services/index.js

Comment: yes, @lost_in_magento It is in my services/index.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code `getApiData` is promise but you just call it in component did mount 
first change the getApiData so we add return to it :

```
 export function getApiData(){
     return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
     .then((data)=>data.json())
     .then((res)=>res)
```

}

now we can access it in didComponet:

```
componentDidMount(){
    getApiData().then(data=>{
       console.log(data);

     //or set in state
     this.setState({result:data})
     });
 }
```

Comment: I already tried this method. It doesn't work.

Comment: @kunal I update my answer

Comment: Thanks @MBehtemam, But can you please explain me, Why do we need to prepend return before fetch. as i already returned res.